# linux C select() never return 0

Tags: c, select, pipe

I have a question with select and pipe. I'm trying to create 3 child processes and each has a pipe to send message to parent process. I'm using `select()` to check if there is any fd ready. My question is I always get non-zero return value from `select()` so my loop won't terminate. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

```
 int pps[3][3];                                 //pipes
 int highestFD=-1;
 fd_set read_set;
 for (i = 0;i<3;i++) {
   if(pipe(pps[i]) != 0) {
            exit(1);
        }
   int ret= fork();
   if (ret== 0) {
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(pps[i][0]);
        dup2(pps[i][1], 1);
        write(1, "something", 100);
        exit(0);                               //child process exit
    }
    if (ret > 0) {
        close(pps[i][1]);
        if (pps[i][0] > highestFD)
          highestFD = pps[i][0];
    }
 }

 while(1) {
    FD_ZERO(&read_set);
    for (i = 0;i<3;i++) {
          FD_SET(pps[i][0], &read_set);
    }
    changedCount = 0;
    changedCount = select(highestFD+1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    if (changedCount <= 0) {
         printf("exit");
         break;
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0;i<3;i++) {
         if (FD_ISSET(pps[i][0], &read_set)) {
            int rc = read(pipes[i][0], buffer, 100);
            if (rc > 0) {
               printf("%s\n",buffer);
               memset(buffer, 0, 100);
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: You don't handle the case where `read` returns less than or equal to zero. What do you expect to happen when the other end closes the pipe?

Comment: So I should remove one fd from watched fd_set if `read()` on it returns less than or equal to zero? I tried `poll()` too, but it also won't terminate. I guess there must be something I missed about pipe communication.

Comment: From `man select`: *If timeout is NULL (no timeout), select() can block indefinitely*. You're not passing any timeout, ergo, the `select` blocks indefinitely, until some fd becomes ready.

Comment: I think that's not my problem, I debugged my code, select() will always return value 3, it won't block.

Comment: The posted code fails to handle the case where the call to `fork()` fails

Comment: what you missed was how to setup `select()` to use a timeout

Answer (score 1):

from the man page for `select()`

```
RETURN VALUE
   On success, select() and pselect() return the number of  file  descrip‐
   tors  contained  in  the  three  returned descriptor sets (that is, the
   total number of bits that are  set  in  readfds,  writefds,  exceptfds)
   which  may  be  zero if the timeout expires before anything interesting
   happens.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately; the
   sets  and  timeout  become  undefined, so do not rely on their contents
   after an error.
```

Notice this statement:

"return the number of  file  descriptors  contained  in  the  three  returned descriptor sets"

which (along with the rest of the man page) says

1. return -1 on error
2. return 0 if timeout occurs
3. return >0 when any of the associated fs's have any data movement to report

So, to return a zero, none of the associated fd's can have input any data and an I/O error did not occur.

So why is a 0 never returned from `select()` in your code?

Answer: because a 0 can only be returned when a timeout occurs and the posted code never setup a timeout.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I can't use 0 value to terminate my loop, how should I stop when I already read everything from all the file descriptors. I had the same situation when I used `poll()` to instead `select()`.

Comment: @qrrq Under what conditions do you want to terminate your loop? When what happens?

Comment: I want to terminate my `while(1)` loop when no new bytes are written into fds. In most case, at that time all three child processes should have exited. I thought `select()` can tell me if there is any fd with new bytes ready to read.

Comment: `select()` does tell you when no FDs have any bytes to read.  However, for that case, need to implement the `timeout` feature of `select()`.

Comment: @qrrq It's really not clear what you mean by "when no new bytes are written". Do you mean when no more new bytes could possibly been written? Or when you've already read all the bytes that have already been written? Or what?

Comment: I think it's the second case. Child process only write the pipe once then exit. Parent process can get all the bytes of one child process in one read.